# why my unix domain socket can't work

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, unix-socket

there are two simple program to demo the unix domain **DGRAM** socket.

```
/* server */
int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    char buf[10];
    int mpLogFD, len;
    struct sockaddr_un serverAddress;

    if((mpLogFD = socket(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
        mpExit("sock");
    unlink(MPLOGD_SOCK);
    memset(&serverAddress, 0, sizeof(serverAddress));
    serverAddress.sun_family = AF_LOCAL;
    strcpy(serverAddress.sun_path, "/var/run/lsvr.sock");
    if(bind(mpLogFD, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0)
        mpExit("bind");
    perror("svr");
    for(;;){
        if(recvfrom(mpLogFD, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddress, &len) < 0)
            mpExit("recv");
        printf("%s\n", buf);
    }
}



/* client */
int main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    int CliFD, len;
    char buf[10];
    struct sockaddr_un cliaddr;

    if((CliFD = socket(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1)
        mpExit("cli sock");
    memset(&cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr));
    cliaddr.sun_family = AF_LOCAL;
    strcpy(cliaddr.sun_path, "/var/run/lcli.sock");
    if(bind(CliFD, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr)))
        mpExit("cli bind");
    len = sizeof(cliaddr);

    sprintf(buf, "12345678\n");

    if(sendto(CliFD, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, len) < 0)
        mpExit("cli send");
    perror("cli");
}
```

and the following is the result:

```
[root@jyl opt]# ./logsvr &            
2033
svr: Success  
[root@jyl opt]# ./logcli              
cli: Success  
[root@jyl opt]#
```

it seems like nothing wrong here. but, I get nothing from the server.
I don't know why it can't run as I expect.

Comment: in the server, there is a missing words that 'len = sizeof(serverAddress);'.

Comment: your client should be sending to /var/run/lsvr.sock not to /var/run/lsvr.sock

Comment: @Pras  thank you for your tip!!!!!   client should not be sending to /var/run/lcli.sock. there is should be a another **sockaddr_un**, which path is the same as **serverAddress**'s path.

Comment: @Pras "*to /var/run/lsvr.sock not to /var/run/lsvr.sock*" well ... ;-)

Comment: @alk :) corrected that in answer

Comment: @umbreLLaJYL In server you bound your socket to "/var/run/lsvr.sock", so in client you should specify same path in the destination address of sendto() call

Comment: `len` in the server shall be of `socklen_t` not `int`, this is critical as its address is passed. Inside the client it's also wrong, but not critical as the value is passed.

Comment: @alk thanks! I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be sending to `/var/run/lsvr.sock` not to `/var/run/lcli.sock`.

Also you don't have to bind in client so comment it out  from client:

```
/*    if(bind(CliFD, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr)))
            mpExit("cli bind");*/
```

Comment: thanks! but, **bind** in the client is needed indeed when initialize a socket into a unix domain DGRAM socket.

Comment: @umbreLLaJYL bind() in client will associate your client socket to a local address/path(it must be different than the server address), you wont sent to local address, you would to send to server address ie address where your server has bound itself

Comment: bind() in client is necessary to complete initializing unix domain socket. otherwise, sendto/write call will fail whose error message is **No such file or directory**.